# Chaining Dispatched Actions with Redux Promise Middleware and JHipster

Tags: reactjs, jhipster, redux-promise-middleware

I am building a Jhipster React generated project. My problem is I couldn't manage to chain reducer functions.

Simply, I want to chain `getSession()` function with another function in the authentication reducer.

In my component I want to handle `then()` operation like `getSession().then(....`

Can you please help for this?

Here is the `authentication.ts` reducer:

### authentication.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Storage } from 'react-jhipster';

import { REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE } from 'app/shared/reducers/action-type.util';

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
    LOGIN: 'authentication/LOGIN',
    GET_SESSION: 'authentication/GET_SESSION',
    LOGOUT: 'authentication/LOGOUT',
    CLEAR_AUTH: 'authentication/CLEAR_AUTH',
    ERROR_MESSAGE: 'authentication/ERROR_MESSAGE'
};

const AUTH_TOKEN_KEY = 'jhi-authenticationToken';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loginSuccess: false,
    loginError: false, // Errors returned from server side
    showModalLogin: false,
    account: {} as any,
    errorMessage: null as string, // Errors returned from server side
    redirectMessage: null as string
};

export type AuthenticationState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;

// Reducer

export default ( state: AuthenticationState = initialState, action ): AuthenticationState => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case REQUEST( ACTION_TYPES.LOGIN ):
        case REQUEST( ACTION_TYPES.GET_SESSION ):
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case FAILURE( ACTION_TYPES.LOGIN ):
            return {
                ...initialState,
                errorMessage: action.payload,
                showModalLogin: true,
                loginError: true
            };
        case FAILURE( ACTION_TYPES.GET_SESSION ):
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                showModalLogin: true,
                errorMessage: action.payload
            };
        case SUCCESS( ACTION_TYPES.LOGIN ):
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                loginError: false,
                showModalLogin: false,
                loginSuccess: true
            };
        case ACTION_TYPES.LOGOUT:
            return {
                ...initialState,
                showModalLogin: true
            };
        case SUCCESS( ACTION_TYPES.GET_SESSION ): {
            const isAuthenticated = action.payload && action.payload.data && action.payload.data.activated;
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated,
                loading: false,
                account: action.payload.data
            };
        }
        case ACTION_TYPES.ERROR_MESSAGE:
            return {
                ...initialState,
                showModalLogin: true,
                redirectMessage: action.message
            };
        case ACTION_TYPES.CLEAR_AUTH:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                showModalLogin: true,
                isAuthenticated: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const displayAuthError = message => ( { type: ACTION_TYPES.ERROR_MESSAGE, message } );

export const getSession = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch( {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.GET_SESSION,
        payload: axios.get( '/api/account' )
    } );
};

export const login = ( username, password, rememberMe = false ) => async ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    const result = await dispatch( {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.LOGIN,
        payload: axios.post( '/api/authenticate', { username, password, rememberMe } )
    } );
    const bearerToken = result.value.headers.authorization;
    if ( bearerToken && bearerToken.slice( 0, 7 ) === 'Bearer ' ) {
        const jwt = bearerToken.slice( 7, bearerToken.length );
        if ( rememberMe ) {
            Storage.local.set( AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, jwt );
        } else {
            Storage.session.set( AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, jwt );
        }
    }
    dispatch( getSession() );
};

export const clearAuthToken = () => {
    if ( Storage.local.get( AUTH_TOKEN_KEY ) ) {
        Storage.local.remove( AUTH_TOKEN_KEY );
    }
    if ( Storage.session.get( AUTH_TOKEN_KEY ) ) {
        Storage.session.remove( AUTH_TOKEN_KEY );
    }
};

export const logout = () => dispatch => {
    clearAuthToken();
    dispatch( {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.LOGOUT
    } );
};

export const clearAuthentication = messageKey => ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    clearAuthToken();
    dispatch( displayAuthError( messageKey ) );
    dispatch( {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.CLEAR_AUTH
    } );
};
```

### store.ts

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer, { IRootState } from 'app/shared/reducers';
import DevTools from './devtools';
import errorMiddleware from './error-middleware';
import notificationMiddleware from './notification-middleware';
import loggerMiddleware from './logger-middleware';
import { loadingBarMiddleware } from 'react-redux-loading-bar';

const defaultMiddlewares = [
  thunkMiddleware,
  errorMiddleware,
  notificationMiddleware,
  promiseMiddleware(),
  loadingBarMiddleware(),
  loggerMiddleware
];
const composedMiddlewares = middlewares =>
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? compose(
        applyMiddleware(...defaultMiddlewares, ...middlewares),
        DevTools.instrument()
      )
    : compose(applyMiddleware(...defaultMiddlewares, ...middlewares));

const initialize = (initialState?: IRootState, middlewares = []) => createStore(reducer, initialState, composedMiddlewares(middlewares));

export default initialize;
```

### Home Component

```
    import './home.css';

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Row, Col, Alert, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import { IRootState } from 'app/shared/reducers';
import { getSession } from 'app/shared/reducers/authentication';

import { getWhoIsInsideInfo, exitVisitor } from 'app/entities/visitor/visitor.reducer';

import { IVisitorInsideInfo } from 'app/shared/model/visitors_inside.model';
import { TextFormat } from 'react-jhipster';
import { APP_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT } from 'app/config/constants';
import VisitorDeleteDialog from 'app/entities/visitor/visitor-delete-dialog';

export interface IHomeProp extends StateProps, DispatchProps { }

const mapStateToProps = ( { authentication, visitorsInsideInfo }: IRootState ) => ( {
    account: authentication.account,
    isAuthenticated: authentication.isAuthenticated,
    visitorInsideList: visitorsInsideInfo.insiderEntities,
    loginSuccess: authentication.loginSuccess
} );

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

const mapDispatchToProps = { getSession, getWhoIsInsideInfo, exitVisitor };

export class Home extends React.Component<IHomeProp> {
    interval: any;
    orgDispatch: any;



    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.renderVisitorsInside = this.renderVisitorsInside.bind( this );
    }


    setListTimer() {
        console.log( 'DIS' );

    }
getList = () => {
        if ( this.props.account && this.props.account.login ) {
            getWhoIsInsideInfo();
        }
    };
.....
}
```

In my Home component I want to first call getSession then call getList. If response was OK else reject it.
Thanks from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything right. You just need to call your reducer functions with `dispatch`.

For example:

```
dispatch(getSession()).then(...)
```

Comment: yes you are right. my mistake was in my component I didn't put the dispatch as parameter. because of that it was complaining.

Comment: sorry for change. I added my home.component but when I tried to dispatch it didnot work.